# Filter insights by server

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using application insights to get telemetry data off of my servers, but there is one server linked to my insights ID that i don't have access to, and it is giving me all sorts of bogus data.  How do i filter out all of the telemetry from that server so that it doesn't appear alongside any of my other telemetry responses?

I know i can go into analytics and filter servers out there, but I'm talking about the main metrics page, the one that sends out alerts, shows a general overview of the servers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there's no easy way to do it.  you'd have to edit the filters on every part on every place in order to customize them, and pin those customized versions to dashboards and never look at the default experiences again.

How is there a server sending telemetry using your key you don't have access to?  is it somewhere else where someone made a copy/paste error and somehow used your key?

i believe you can contact support and have them generate a new instrumentation key for that resource.  then you'd update the places you do have under your control to use the new ikey, and the thing not under your control would still be using the old, now invalid key.

Comment: one of my developers deployed the wrong key to a site, and can't remember which site it is that is using that key.  Generating a new key might be my best option then, thank you!